# Switch on LED after receiving Ethernet packets

Tags: vhdl

I'm a novice in VHDL programming and currently try to execute a program where the LED on the FPGA board should switch on after transmitting every 10 Ethernet packets which I generate from a Linux server. The code I've written is in the following which doesn't work properly. I'm trying to figure out the problem but still undone. Any help would be much appreciated.

```css
---------------------------------------------

library IEEE;

use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;
use IEEE.std_logic_arith.all;
use IEEE.std_logic_unsigned.all;

---------------------------------------------

entity notification is 

port (clk, reset, qdv: in std_logic;
      LED: out std_logic
      );
end notification;
  
architecture behavior of notification is
signal qdv_a: std_logic;
signal qdv_b: std_logic;
signal packet_count: std_logic_vector (3 downto 0);


begin

no_1: process(clk, reset)

begin

if (reset = '1') then
 qdv_a <= '0';
elsif rising_edge (clk) then
 qdv_a <= qdv;
end if;
end process no_1;
qdv_b <= qdv and (not qdv_a);

no_2: process(clk, reset)
begin
if (reset = '1') then
 packet_count <= "0000";
elsif rising_edge (clk) then
 if qdv_b = '1' then 
  if packet_count < "1010" then
     packet_count <= packet_count + 1;
     LED <= '0';
  else 
     LED <= '1';
     packet_count <= (others => '0');
  end if;
 end if;
end if;
end process no_2;

end behavior;
```

Comment: First - you don't write programs in VHDL, you design hardware. Difference is important, because you have to think in completely different way. Second - never use `std_logic_arith` and `std_logic_unsigned`, use `numeric_std` instead. Read [here](https://vhdlguru.blogspot.com/2010/03/why-library-numericstd-is-preferred.html) why. Third - rising_edge(), when used for synthesis, is for clock signals only. is qdv a clock? Besides, it can not work, even in simulation, because qdv is not in the sensitivity list, and you can't detect it's rising edge because of that.

Comment: This question is a follow up on your last question and IMO doesn't warrant a new question. Also, I already told you last time not to use `std_logic_arith` and that you do not need to use it anyway. I also wrote that the asynchronous reset probably is a bad idea and cited sources.

Comment: I've edited the code according to the suggestions from @Matthew Taylor..However, need to run the processes sequentially. Is it possible to insert a wait statement in between to run those processes sequentially?

Answer (score 2):

I am making assumptions based on your code:

1) You are trying to increment `packet_count` every time you see a rising edge on `qdv`,

2) The pulse width of `qdv` is longer than a period of the 25MHz clock (`clk_25MHz`) - 40ns and

3) You want an asynchronous reset. (Trying to decide which is better - a synchronous or asynchronous reset - is like trying to decide which is a better - a Mac or a PC.)

So,

If (1) and (2) are true, you need a *synchronous edge detector*:

```
signal qdv_d : std_logic;
signal qdv_r : std_logic;
...
process (clk_25MHz, reset)
begin
  if reset = '1' then
    qdv_d <= '0';
  elsif rising_edge (clk_25MHz) then
    qdv_d <= qdv;
  end if;
end process;
qdv_r <= qdv and not qdv_d;
```

Please draw this out as a schematic so that you can see how it works.

Then, assuming (3), you need to sort out your main process. If you're coding sequential logic, you should stick to a template. Here is the template for sequential logic with an asynchronous reset, which all synthesis tools should understand:

```
process(clock, async_reset)  -- nothing else should go in the sensitivity list
begin
    -- never put anything here
    if async_reset ='1' then  -- or '0' for an active low reset
        -- set/reset the flip-flops here
        -- ie drive the signals to their initial values
    elsif rising_edge(clock) then  -- or falling_edge(clock)
        -- put the synchronous stuff here
        -- ie the stuff that happens on the rising or falling edge of the clock
    end if;
     -- never put anything here
end process;
```

Only clock and reset go in the sensitivity list, because the outputs of the sequential process (though they depend on all the inputs) only change when clock and/or reset change. On a real D-type flip-flop, reset takes priority over clock, so we test that first and do the resetting should reset be asserted. If there is a change on clock (when reset is not asserted) and that change is a rising edge, then do all the stuff that should happen on the rising edge of a clock (stuff that will get synthesised to combinational logic driving the D inputs of the flip-flops).

So, using that template, here is how I would write your main process:

```
process(clk_25MHz, reset)
begin
  if reset = '1' then
    packet_count <= "0000";
  elsif rising_edge (clk_25MHz) then
    if qdv_r = '1' then
      if packet_count < "1010" then
        packet_count <= packet_count + 1;
        LED <= '0';
      else 
        LED <= '1';
        packet_count <= (others => '0');
      end if;
    end if;
  end if;
end process;
```

Now we have a synchronous process which increments `packet_count` and drives the `LED` output. (What is `q` bringing to the party?)

Please

- bear in mind that I haven't simulated any of this
- don't just type it in without trying to understand how it works

Comment: Your assumption is absolutely correct. However, now there are two processes which I need to run sequentially. The first process is for synchronous edge detection and the second one is my main process. Is it possible to use a wait statement between those two processes? # Matthew Taylor

Comment: @AbdullahAlMamunA Run them sequentially? That makes no sense. VHDL is a HARDWARE description language. We're designing hardware here, not writing software. Everything between `begin` and `end architecture;` runs concurrently. That's for a reason: that's what hardware does.

Comment: Sorry for my stupid question as I told at the beginning that still I'm a  novice in this field. I tried to run the edited code according to your suggestion, where two processes run concurrently. However, that doesn't work for me. That's why trying to find a way to run both processes sequentially which doesn't make any sense. @Matthew Taylor

Comment: @AbdullahAlMamun Don't worry about asking questions; if you don't ask questions, you don't learn. Your question was a bit worrying, because it shows you have a fundamental concept you need to grasp.

Comment: @AbdullahAlMamun You say your code isn't working. Are you simulating it? Or just synthesising and testing on the FPGA? If you're not simulating it, I highly recommend you write a testbench and do so. Then you can debug why it isn't working. In your testbench, you'll have to generate clock and reset inputs and also generate the `qdv` input.